# Why can't I import two modules in PyCharm?

Tags: python, import, pycharm

I want to import two packages in PyCharm but the second import is always ignored (it is gray). Why is this?

```
  import requests
  import csv
```

Comment: gray means you don't use that module yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pycharm (if I get your question correctly), if you are not using a module or a variable, it gets grayed out. That's it. Also if you import the same module somewhere else in your code, one of them is grayed out.

Comment: `Also if you import the same module somewhere else in your code`, isn't considered a good approach.
Modules should always be imported in the header of the script.

Comment: @taurus05 Unfortunately, things are not always that simple. Most notably, when you call a function after a fork, you might encounter problems if that function uses modules but does not import them by itself (ie right after the `def`). So in some cases, you might need to import the same module multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are not using the module in your python script, it will remain grey.
The moment you use it, it will become coloured.

This is an IDE feature, particularly useful to keep the code clean, by removing unused imports. A similar functionality happens when you try to create a variable and do not use it's value in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Pycharm grays out the import statements that are not used in your code. It seems your code does not use the csv package. It will become colored once you use it.